# Genesys-How to get selected queue info and specify multiple statistic metric

Tags: c#, .net, genesys

Once again, I know it's a rare topic here, I just try my luck here to get some idea.

I'm new to Genesys and currently I'm developing an agent desktop with PSDK 8.5 and C#.NET. In my agent desktop, there is a listview for displaying selected virtual queue info. I'm able to connect to CCPulse and Stat Server programmatically, the problem is I don't know how to select specific virtual queue info even I've read the Genesys documentation.

Here's what I've got from CCPulse:

[image]

As I referred to the documentation, to get the information of certain object, have to do something like:

```
//Requests that Stat Server start sending information about a predefined statistics
RequestOpenStatistic requestOpenStatistic = RequestOpenStatistic.Create();

//Describe the statistic object (the monitored object)
requestOpenStatistic.StatisticObject = StatisticObject.Create();
requestOpenStatistic.StatisticObject.ObjectId = "prepaid_vqs";
requestOpenStatistic.StatisticObject.ObjectType = StatisticObjectType.GroupQueues;
requestOpenStatistic.StatisticObject.TenantName = "Environment";
requestOpenStatistic.StatisticObject.TenantPassword = "";
```

**Question 1**: How can I get to the *"prepaid_vq"* which is under *"prepaid_vqs"*? Based on the statements above, I can reach to *"prepaid_vqs"* level, but don't know how to reach to *"prepaid_vq"*.

After describing the StatisticObject, then have to describe the StatisticMetric:

```
requestOpenStatistic.StatisticMetric = StatisticMetric.Create();
requestOpenStatistic.StatisticMetric.StatisticType = "CurrNumberWaitingCalls";
```

**Question 2**: How can I specify multiple statistic metric (eg. ServiceFactor, CurrNumberWaitingCalls) at one time and send them together under the same ReferenceId? I need to get more than one statistic info for one virtual queue.

So at the end, this is my expected result to be display on the agent desktop:

[image]

Any Genesys Guru here please help.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no easy way to dynamically get the VQ's for a particular agent. We had to write a proprietary solution that crawls through CME and maps the agent to their VQ's. It was very difficult. The alternative is to use a configuration source that your app can call where you can pre-define what the agent's VQ's are. This is how Genesys  Interaction Workspace and now Workspace Desktop Edition works.

2) You cannot specify multiple statistic metrics at one time without creating your own custom defined stat on the stat server. You would never want to reuse the same reference id across multiple stats, because then you would not be able to correlate the response back to it's respective stat.

Comment: Hi @EricScherre, thanks for your suggestions. For your point 1, actually it can be done like this:
requestOpenStatistic.StatisticObject.ObjectId = "virtualQ@switchName";
For your point 2, I solved it by using four for loop, each metric for each loop, then inside each loop, loop the virtual queues.

Comment: OK sorry, I misread your question... For 1 I thought you wanted to know how to get the VQ's for an agent, not how to pass them along to the stat server.